# Does the heap management in a stl priority queue call the copy constructor?

Tags: c++, stl, c++11, priority-queue

I know the stl priority queue uses `make_heap`, `push_heap`, and `pop_heap` to manage the underlying stl container (a vector, for example).

Are the elements' copy constructors being called when moving elements around during the `make_heap`, `push_heap`, and `pop_heap` calls?

Comment: This is completely implementation dependent.

Comment: How can I check what my implementation does?

Comment: By checking the source code, ofcourse.

Comment: From your comment to one of the answers it seems you are asking this in a C++11 context. Due to the availability of move semantics in C++11, this makes a difference. Should the C++11 tag be added to the question?

Comment: @jogojapan Sure, I didn't realize this was a specific to C++11 until digging around a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the standard, `push_heap` and `make_heap` require the value type (`*iterator`) to be `MoveAssignable` and `MoveConstructible`; `pop_heap` and `sort_heap` also require the iterator type to be `ValueSwappable`, which requires `swap` to work, which also requires the value type to be `MoveAssignable` and `MoveConstructible`.

My interpretation is that the standard library can only invoke operations which can be satisfied with move semantics, which could be tested by trying it on a container whose value type's copy constructor and copy assignment operator have been deleted.

By way of a quick verification, I tried the heap functions on a datatype whose move constructor and move assignment operator were deleted. Both gcc 4.7.2 and clang 3.2 generated compile-time errors complaining that the move operations were deleted. The test with deleted copy operations compiled just fine.

Answer (score 2):

I tested my implementation. It uses only move constructors and move assignments. Since the underlying type is typical a vector or a deque, I can't see how you can do any better.

You can test yourself by creating a dummy class with just one int (needed for compairing objects) and putting print statements in the default constructor, the copy constructor, the move constructor, the copy assignment operator and the move assignemt operator.

Comment: Yeah, I'm seeing calls to `_GLIBCXX_MOVE` (defined to be `std::move`) in my implementation of the stl heap stuff.

Answer (score -1):

Although this is implementation-dependant, most sensible implementations will use std::swap to move elements around, therefore avoiding copying overhead.

Comment: The std::swap reference (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/swap/) says: "Notice how this function involves a copy construction and two assignment operations, which may not be the most efficient way of swapping the contents of classes that store large quantities of data, since each of these operations generally operate in linear time on their size." So, if std::swap is used, I don't think this avoids copying overhead.

Comment: @Sancho If you read the next paragraph, it explains that all STL containers specialize swap to avoid this overhead.

Comment: @Yuushi You misunderstand what is specialized. The paragraph means that you can swap two containers efficiently due to the specializations, not that you can swap two elements within the containers. The STL cannot magically make your user defined class efficiently swappable.

Comment: @imaginaryboy My mistake, you're correct. I didn't read the question properly.

Comment: That's all a moot point -- the _C++ standard_ defines `std::swap` in terms of moves, not copies (20.2.2/2). This is just a case of cplusplus.com being shit as usual.